# How to disable client-side validation for a single view?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I need to disable client-side validation for a form on a single view.

How do I do this?

I do not want to just disable the following JS files:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Do you want to disable Unobtrosive validation globally? Or just for one page?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Brad Wilson describes this in his blog post: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html - I have highlighted the bits that answers your question (the last line) in the following quote from the blog post:

> To turn unobtrusive JavaScript mode on/off and enable/disable client validation by default for the entire application, you can use Web.config:
>
> ```
> <configuration>
>     <appSettings>
>         <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
>         <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
>     </appSettings>
> </configuration>
> ```
>
> You can also turn them on or off with code:
>
> ```
> HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = true;
> HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true;
> ```
>
> Using code to turn these features on or off actually behaves
>   contextually. If those lines of code are present in your Global.asax
>   file, then it turns unobtrusive JavaScript and client validation on or
>   off for the whole application. ***If they appear within your
>   controller or view, on the other hand, it will turn the features on or
>   off for the current action only.***