# MVC Form action method gets overwritten

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, razor, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have the following razor form:

```
@model
@using (Html.BeginForm("ResetPassword", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.Hidden("guid", ViewData["guid"]) ....ect it contains a model and 1 hidden field
```

When i hit the page i must pass a guid i do this the following way:

```
User/ResetPassword/8C5F38CC-C8DB-46B4-80F5-169699D8A583
```

I hit the action controller as expected:

```
 public ActionResult ResetPassword(string id)
        {
            ViewBag.Title = @DDHelper.GetContent("user_password_reset_new") + " " +
                @DDHelper.GetContent("slogan") + " " + @DDHelper.GetMeta("sitename");

            if (id != null)
            {
                Guid pwID = new Guid();
                if (Guid.TryParse(id, out pwID))
                {
                    if (UserManager.GetResetPasswordUser(pwID) != null)
                    {
                        ViewData["guid"] = id;
                        return View(new Models.User());
                    }
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Now when i look at the html razor produced i see:

```
<form action="/User/ResetPassword/8C5F38CC-C8DB-46B4-80F5-169699D8A583" class="form-horizontal" method="post" role="form">
```

When i post the form i want to hit the action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ResetPassword(Models.User pwUser)
{
    string guid = Request["guid"];
    string password = pwUser.Password;

    Guid pwID = new Guid();

    if (Guid.TryParse(guid, out pwID))
    {             
        UserManager.ResetUserPassword(password,pwID);
        return RedirectToAction("LogOn");
    }

    return View(guid);
}
```

Now when I post the form I hit the cshtml again and i am not hitting my action because the action

```
/User/ResetPassword/8C5F38CC-C8DB-46B4-80F5-169699D8A583
```

does not exsist and everytime someone hits this page the guid is different.
How can i tell the html.beginform to not write parameters in the action name? and why is razor behaving like this?

Comment: ps it took me 30 minites to try and let the code formatter accept my question. in the end it accepted this formatting and it ruined the first lines of code sorry for that.

Comment: If your not hitting your POST method, it has nothing to do with the route parameter. You need to show you controller methods

Comment: its in the question: when someone enters the page it hits: public ActionResult ResetPassword(string id) when someone submits it must hit: [HttpPost] [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] public ActionResult ResetPassword(Models.User pwUser)

Comment: Which it will (because you have specified `FormMethod.Post`!)

Comment: It does not hit [HttpPost] [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] public ActionResult ResetPassword(Models.User pwUser) I have breakpoints there and throw exceptions it only stops In the razor breakpoints

Comment: _"and why is razor behaving like this"_ - because thats how it works. You have a route with `url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",` and your method has a parameter named `id` so its added by default

Comment: You need to show more details of your GET method and POST method - the addition of the route parameter is not the cause of your problem

Comment: I added the method bodies, however it doesnt even break on the first line of the post.

Comment: The Model validation prevented the postback. i dont understand why it must be valid becouse i did not use the [ValidateModel] attribute. Can i disable it for this action?

Comment: I assume you mean client side validation. You can disable it for a view, but why would you want to post back an invalid model?

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278781/how-to-disable-client-side-validation-for-a-single-view) for disabling validation in an individual view